# DISTINCT in laravel ELOQUENT issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, distinct

In my laravel application I have two tables called, apps and app_payments.I wanted to join the two tables and I did it as mentioned in the below laravel ELOQUENT. In the joined table, I have one column to store user ids (user_id). The following ELOQUENT returns me multiple rows for certain user

```
$sites=DB::table('app_payments')
        ->join('apps', 'app_payments.app_id', '=', 'apps.appId')
        ->select('app_payments.*', 'apps.*')
        ->where ('apps.appId','=',$id)
        ->get();
return view('payments.show',compact('sites'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 100);
```

But I only need to select one row for one (specific) user id, I know I might have to use DISTINCT there but, struggling to use it in this laravel ELOQUENT.

How can I modify above ELOQUENT to achieve that?

Comment: if you only want one user, add that criteria to the query with `->where('app_payments', '=', $userId)`. Distinct does not enter into this, as it is only used to suppress duplicate results. I would assume there would be no duplicate payments. This should return payments only for the user specified

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is using the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#introduction) (`DB::table('app_payments')->...`), not [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent) (`AppPayment::where(...)->...->get()`)

What is your aim to get from those tables? Continuing doing it with the Query Builder directly or with Eloquent, expanding the Query Builder?

In Eloquent, you would setup the [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships) between app and payments in the Model:

```
public function app()
{
  $this->belongsTo(App::class, 'appId');
}
public function user()
{
  $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Something like

```
AppPayment::where('appId', $id)->with(['app', 'user'])->get()
```

would return all Payments with the corresponding App and User.

Of course, when you expect to only get one payment per user, this will not yet do the job.  To me, that sounds like you better query the other way around, but that decision depends on what data you actually need.

For the **last** payment, this would be something like:

```
// App\Models\User.php
...
public function payments()
  return $this->hasMany(AppPayment::class)
    ->with(['app'])
    ->orderByDesc('created_at');
...

// query anywhere
$users = User::with(['payments', 'payment.app'])
  ->whereHas('payments', function (Builder $query) use($app_id){
    $query->where('app_id', $app_id);
  })
  ->get()

// latest payment:
foreach($users as $user){
  $latestPayment = $user->payments[0];
  ...
}
```

Code untested though... And it still needs a trick to only (!) get the latest payment of a specific app, I lost that point out of sight...

Comment: this way of coding is not efficient, laravel runs too many queries to fetch the data if coded like this. Joins are more preferable

Comment: Thx! Learnt that some time ago and switched to joins inside eloquent scopes the way Jonathan Reinink points out in [his eloquent course](https://eloquent-course.reinink.ca).

Either way, you've got to decide if using Eloquent or DB.

Comment: Yeah using joins is a lot more efficient than using the eloquent relations, you could still stick to eloquent and add DB::raw whenever needed for certain columns and stuff. The article you mentioned seems good.